# Insert ongoing number to multiple files - linux console

Tags: awk, sed, printf, cat, fold

I'm having a bigger file (16192 times 0) that I need to split up into 500 character segments.

I do it like that:

`split 1.txt -b500 1_split.txt`

This gives me 33 files with 1_split.txtaa to 1_split.txtbg

I need to have a text with ongoing number in each file now -
like

```
parts:
1=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

in 1_split.txtaa till part 33 in 1_split.txtbf

It would be farorable to have it even like that

```
parts:
1=000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h 000h
```

As I need it in a strange formatting with leading 2 and trailing h for every byte - seperated with spaces :(

For this I played around with fold but unfortunately it gives me a strange output by doing

```
cat 1_split.txt* | fold -w2 | paste -sd 'h'
```

Unfortunately it gives me `00h 0h0`  already at the beginning instead of
`00h 00h`

Nor do I know how to save the changes to the just opened file yet. Also `fold -w0` doesn't work so I don't know if its good to add the leading 0.

Is it something somebody would rather do with echo, printf, awk or sed? :(

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Jonas

Comment: You could do a loop in awk and loop over your variable, assigning 3 characters at a time using `substr(str, start, l)` into an array  `s[i]`. Then print this array with h and space.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (e.g. 16 0s split into groups 5 instead of  16000+ 0s split into groups of 500) as it's not clear what you're trying to do or what problem you're having doing whatever it is.

Comment: Your *favorable* example looks strange because it seems dropping two zeros
out of every five zeros rather than just dividing the sequence, appending
`h` to each chunks and putting spaces in between, judging from the length
of the strings. As Ed Morton comments,
it is reccomended to clarify the requirements with minimized examples.

Answer (score 0):

the `substring`-ing bits to 500 apiece should be relatively trivial. Here's a code snippet that takes `integer` inputs at `$1` starting with `1`, and returns a `2-letter` sequence akin to how split name their files sequentially.

- The 2 constants used inside are `26` and `97 ( ascii # 4 "a" )`.

It shouldn't be too hard to expand its alphabet range to all `[:alpha:]` within `ASCII` instead of just lowercase

```
{m,g}awk 'BEGIN { __ = (_+=_+=_^=_<_)^--_-_+_*_*++_+\
                      !(___ = -(_-++_*++_)) + !(_^=!_)

} $++NF = sprintf("%c%c", int((____=-_+$_)/___)+__, ____%___+__) '



 1 aa   58 cf   115 ek  172 gp  229 iu  286 kz  343 ne  400 pj  457 ro  514 tt  571 vy  628 yd
 5 ae   62 cj   119 eo  176 gt  233 iy  290 ld  347 ni  404 pn  461 rs  518 tx  575 wc  632 yh
 9 ai   66 cn   123 es  180 gx  237 jc  294 lh  351 nm  408 pr  465 rw  522 ub  579 wg  636 yl
 13 am  70 cr   127 ew  184 hb  241 jg  298 ll  355 nq  412 pv  469 sa  526 uf  583 wk  640 yp
 
 17 aq  74 cv   131 fa  188 hf  245 jk  302 lp  359 nu  416 pz  473 se  530 uj  587 wo  644 yt
 21 au  78 cz   135 fe  192 hj  249 jo  306 lt  363 ny  420 qd  477 si  534 un  591 ws  648 yx
 25 ay  82 dd   139 fi  196 hn  253 js  310 lx  367 oc  424 qh  481 sm  538 ur  595 ww  652 zb
 29 bc  86 dh   143 fm  200 hr  257 jw  314 mb  371 og  428 ql  485 sq  542 uv  599 xa  656 zf
 
 33 bg  90 dl   147 fq  204 hv  261 ka  318 mf  375 ok  432 qp  489 su  546 uz  603 xe  660 zj
 37 bk  94 dp   151 fu  208 hz  265 ke  322 mj  379 oo  436 qt  493 sy  550 vd  607 xi  664 zn
 41 bo  98 dt   155 fy  212 id  269 ki  326 mn  383 os  440 qx  497 tc  554 vh  611 xm  668 zr
 45 bs  102 dx  159 gc  216 ih  273 km  330 mr  387 ow  444 rb  501 tg  558 vl  615 xq  672 zv
 
 49 bw  106 eb  163 gg  220 il  277 kq  334 mv  391 pa  448 rf  505 tk  562 vp  619 xu  676 zz
 53 ca  110 ef  167 gk  224 ip  281 ku  338 mz  395 pe  452 rj  509 to  566 vt  623 xy
 57 ce  114 ej  171 go  228 it  285 ky  342 nd  399 pi  456 rn  513 ts  570 vx  627 yc
```